# Reading input from webcam using python-opencv: preview window not responding

Tags: python, opencv, visual-c++

I tried this code, my inbuilt webcam switches on, I'm a getting a preview window but video is not displayed. It simply says *not responding*.

I tried this code with OpenCV 2.4.10 , python 2.7 and even with OpenCV 3.0, 3.1 but no result.

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("preview") 
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame 
    rval, frame = vc.read() 
else:    
    rval = False

while rval: 
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame) 
    rval, frame = vc.read() 
    key = cv2.waitKey(20) 
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC 
        break 

cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Comment: Please check that I didn't get indentation wrong. Have you tried `read()` the frame _before_ `imshow()`?

Comment: import cv2

cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break

cv2.destroyWindow("preview")

Comment: There's an _edit_ link under the question. You can use it to format your question properly

Comment: yes sir, i have tried as said...i used frame=vc.read() before imshow()...still window shows no response

Comment: I ran your code (verbatim) on my machine. It works just fine. I have OpenCV 2.4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04. I would suggest that you should try loading a saved video instead of live camera. If your video is displayed correctly, then it may be a hardware issue. If it isn't, there may be a configuration issue in OpenCV